# Microsoft WPF Designer Value For Property Not Updating When Changed By Another Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, dependency-properties, designer

Similar questions have been asked for WinForms projects, but not for WPF projects.

This VERY simple sample below shows the issue.  The real user control I have is much more complicated but this sample shows the basic issue I am having.

The *UserControl1* xaml (nothing there as it doesn't need anything to show the issue)

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProperty.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
  <Grid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The *Window* xaml (just contains a *UserControl1*):

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:TestProperty="clr-namespace:TestProperty;assembly=TestProperty" x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>
    <TestProperty:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The actual *Window* code-behind is really nothing

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code-behind for *UserControl1*.  Has two properties where the first property simply modifies the second to be the same.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestProperty
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Description("Sets a test property value that sets another property.")]
        [Category("UserControl1")]
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
        public bool TestValue1
        {
            get => (bool) GetValue(TestValue1Property);
            set => SetValue(TestValue1Property, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestValue1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "TestValue1", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                                              new PropertyChangedCallback(TestValue1Changed)));
        private static void TestValue1Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
            ((UserControl1) d)?.TestValue1Changed(e);
        private void TestValue1Changed(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestValue2 = (bool) e.NewValue;
            InvalidateProperty(TestValue2Property);
        }

        [Description("Value should change automatically when TestValue1 changes.")]
        [Category("UserControl1")]
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
        public bool TestValue2
        {
            get => (bool) GetValue(TestValue2Property);
            set => SetValue(TestValue2Property, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestValue2Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "TestValue2", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                                              new PropertyChangedCallback(TestValue2Changed)));
        private static void TestValue2Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
            ((UserControl1) d)?.TestValue2Changed(e);
        private void TestValue2Changed(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            InvalidateProperty(TestValue2Property);
        }
    }
}
```

The attribute *RefreshProperties* and the call to *InvalidateProperty* appear to do nothing.

When editing the *MainWindow.xaml* and selecting *UserControl1*, the *UserControl1* section of the Properties window shows *TestValue1* and *TestValue2*.  If *TestValue1* is changed, *TestValue2* does NOT change.  However, if you change to another Visual Studio (or Blend) editor window and then back to the *MainWindow.xaml*, then *TestValue2* will be the same as *TestValue1*.

I cannot seem to find any method to automatically have *TestValue2* update when *TestValue1* forces the update.  The real case is obviously more complex with quite a few controls and when adding our *UserControl*, we want the designer to be able to specify several properties that can result in forcing (or coercing) other properties.  However, the designer needs to be able to see the property value changes without having to switch to another file and back again to redraw the designer's properties window.

Is this something that simply can't be done - or is there something I'm missing.  Note that this is a *UserControl* and is not designed to operate itself MVVM, but allow another window to be designed using the control with (or without) MVVM design.

Also, in a 'kind of' related issue.  We have one property that needs to have an entry in the properties the same as *Width* and *Height* with the *auto* button.  When set to *Auto* display **"Auto (nnn)"** as the automatically set value changes *nnn* changes.  When not set, the value is simply *nnn* and is defined during the design of the window using the *UserControl*.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed light on this.

Comment: It is a well-known fact that the designer isn't on par with say, runtime execution of your program. In short, run your program to assert it's working as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it isn't that great and there are other 3rd party designers (which I don't want all uses of my control to have to use a 3rd party to use this control).  But -- it would seem pretty reasonable to have some 'invalidate' call that triggers the designer's property window (grid) to either redraw entirely or one property.  I've tried everything - including a coercion call to the property being changed.  I see no way for a property not being edited to be redrawn except for the built-in 'Width' and 'Height' which does redraw.  Seems really flaky.

Comment: Been trying to look at this and yeah it's flawed. I can feel your frustration right now, FWIW, a binding does refresh instantly the properties window.

Comment: I'm going to try this - using another non browsable and bind it to the second 'real' property and change it instead and let the binding change the second property and see if that gets around the issue.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll post if it works when I get a chance to try it.